# Prevent/allow a hyperlink click conditionally through Ajax in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to implement a hyperlink on a page which when clicked, will submit through ajax first, run a couple checks determining whether or not the user has the authority to visit the hyperlink-page, and then either allow them to go through or prevent the hyperlink's default action(and raise errors).

I've set up the code, and the ajax request will go through, but will not be handled server-side.

Here is the template code:

```
<a class='btn btn-primary pairing-CTA-btn' href="{% url 'profile:request' object.user %}">Send {{object.user | upper}} a Request</a>
```

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $myButton = $('.pairing-CTA-btn')
    $myButton.click(function(event){
        var $buttonData = $(this).serialize()
        var $endpoint = $myButton.attr('data-url') || window.location.href // or set your own url

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: $endpoint,
            data: $buttonData,
            success: handleSuccess,
            error: handleError,
        })
    })

    function handleSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // No need to do anything here. Allow link click.
        console.log(data)
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(jqXHR)
    }

    function handleError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // on error, prevent default, bring up errors
        event.preventDefault()
        // $('.pairing-CTA-btn-errors').text("YOU SHALL NOT CLICK BUTTON");
        // $('.pairing-CTA-btn-errors').show();
        console.log(jqXHR)
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(errorThrown)
    }
})
```

The View where this link exists:

```
class ProfileDetailView(AjaxRequestButtonMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'user_profile/profile_detail.html'
```

What am I missing in connecting the hyperlink click to the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prevent default inside the `click()` event, instead of inside the `handleError` callback.

The `event` doesn't exist inside the `handleError` function, and since it's an Ajax request, the execution is asynchronous (unless you make the Ajax request synchronous).

So, basically revert the logic: **Deny by default, allow on success**. Instead of allow by default, deny on error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $myButton = $('.pairing-CTA-btn')
    $myButton.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()  // <- here

        var $buttonData = $(this).serialize()
        var $endpoint = $myButton.attr('data-url') || window.location.href // or set your own url

        $.ajax({
            // ...
        })
    })

    function handleSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // send the user to the link
        window.location = $myButton.attr("href");
    }

    function handleError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // ...
    }
})
```

Comment: You are right! I'm so used to define the error / success handler as an anonymous function inside the Ajax definition that I didn't pay attention to this detail. See the update.